# Как получить количество времени, которое прошло с указанной даты?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Я использую библиотеку moment js.
У меня есть переменная `lastupdate` в которой хранится дата последнего обновления. В сообщении я должен вывести: 'сколько дней прошло с последнего обновления'.
Я думаю нужно использовать `moment.duration`. Но если я вывожу `moment.duration(nowDate - lastUpdate)` выдает ошибку.
Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const lastUpdateDate = moment('01.12.2019', 'DD.MM.YYYY'), 
      daysSinceUpdate = moment().diff(lastUpdateDate, 'days'); 
console.log(`С последнего обновления прошло ${daysSinceUpdate} дней`);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Официальная документация ➝ Display ➝ [Difference](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)